# Convert varchar=> Datetime stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to convert a `varchar` into `Datetime` datatype (DATESX = UDDT, datetime). I know what I have to use :

```
CONVERT(datetime, '@adx_en_cours_etude')
```

but I don't see where I can add this convert function ...

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ps_ListingElem]
    @aid_cdi = 5058,
    @adx_en_cours_etude  = '2007-05-23 00:00:00.000'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO


/*My stored procedure :*/
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_ListingElem]
    @aid_cdi ID, /* uddt */
    /* (DATESX = User defined datatype = datetime type)  */
    @adx_en_cours_etude  DATESX,    
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    pc_sup.dt_deb,
    pc_sup.dt_fin,
    pc_sup.id_type_produit,
  FROM     pc_sup
    INNER JOIN type_prod ON pc_sup.id_type_prod = type_prod.id_type_prod
    INNER JOIN cdi_type_prod ON type_prod.id_type_prod = cdi_type_prod.id_type_prod

  WHERE   cdi_type_prod.id_cdi = @aid_cdi
      AND   (@adx_en_cours_etude IS NULL 
      OR    pc_sup.dt_deb <= @adx_en_cours_etude  
      AND   pc_sup.dt_fin >= @adx_en_cours_etude ) 
END
```

Comment: What are these datatypes? What DBMS are you using? ID and DATESX are not standard SQL Server datatypes.

Comment: MS Management Studio (SQL Server 2005)

ID and DATESX = User Defined Datatypes both

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Let me know if it works or need some tunning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pc_sup.dt_deb` `and pc_sup.dt_fin` both Datetime

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ps_ListingElem]
    @aid_cdi = 5058,
    @adx_en_cours_etude  = '2007-05-23 00:00:00.000'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

/*My stored procedure :*/

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[ps_ListingElem]
@aid_cdi ID, /* uddt */
/* (DATESX = User defined datatype = datetime type)  */
@adx_en_cours_etude  DATESX,    

AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    pc_sup.dt_deb,
    pc_sup.dt_fin,
    pc_sup.id_type_produit,
  FROM     pc_sup
    INNER JOIN type_prod ON pc_sup.id_type_prod = type_prod.id_type_prod
    INNER JOIN cdi_type_prod ON type_prod.id_type_prod = cdi_type_prod.id_type_prod

  WHERE   cdi_type_prod.id_cdi = @aid_cdi
      AND   (CONVERT(DATETIME, @adx_en_cours_etude) IS NULL 
      OR    pc_sup.dt_deb <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @adx_en_cours_etude)  
      AND   pc_sup.dt_fin >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @adx_en_cours_etude) ) 

END
```

Answer (score 0):

are you referring to the EXEC statement ?

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ps_ListingElem]
                         @aid_cdi = 5058,
                         @adx_en_cours_etude  = '2007-05-23 00:00:00.000'
```

you don't have to convert. Specifying the date in string ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) as what you have done is fine for SQL Server. You don't have to convert to datetime at all.